Shell scripting: How to replace multiple lines by another set of multiple lines in a file
I am new to shell scripting and I ran into an issue with the following. I am trying to create a type of script which is able to replace multiple lines in a file with another set of multiple lines (with a different size)
I tried to create a text file with the multi-line string i would like to replace (before.txt), a file with a multiline string of the text I would like to see (after.txt) and the original file (original.yml.new). The files contain the following information/structure.
(sidenote: As you can see, the files contain some 'weird' symbols like | ; . : / _)
before.txt:
      - range: XXX.YYY.ZZZZ  
        options: |
          deny dynamic bootp clients;
          allow unknown-clients;       
      - range: dynamic-bootp AAA.BBB.CCC.
        options: |
          allow dynamic bootp clients;
          option root-path "KKK.LLL.MMM:/000.000.000";
          filename "ABCDEF";
          allow unknown-clients;          
    - tag: s_net

After.txt:
      - range: XXX.YYY.ZZZZ  
        options: |
          deny dynamic bootp clients;
          allow unknown-clients;      
          deny members of "cid_xxx.yyy.zzz"; 
      - range: dynamic-bootp AAA.BBB.CCC.
        options: |
          allow dynamic bootp clients;
          option root-path "KKK.LLL.MMM:/000.000.000";
          filename "ABCDEF";
          allow unknown-clients; 
          deny members of "cid_xxx.yyy.zzz";         
    - tag: s_net

original.yml.new:
[Some random number of strings]
      - range: XXX.YYY.ZZZZ  
        options: |
          deny dynamic bootp clients;
          allow unknown-clients;       
      - range: dynamic-bootp AAA.BBB.CCC.
        options: |
          allow dynamic bootp clients;
          option root-path "KKK.LLL.MMM:/000.000.000";
          filename "ABCDEF";
          allow unknown-clients;          
    - tag: s_net
[Some random number of strings]

I've tried to follow the info provided in text and made this oneliner code:
perl -i -0 -p0e "s/$(cat before.txt)/$(cat after.txt)/se" original.yml.new

Output yields:
Number found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "123.456.789.000 123.654.127.172"
    (Missing operator before  123.654.127.172?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "range:"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.


Hope I have provided sufficient information :)

YAML is not really line-oriented; you want to think in terms of arrays and objects, which just happen to be serialized as lines of text. Use a tool that understands and outputs YAML.

Don't (attempt to) generate Perl code from the shell. See How can I process options using Perl in -n or -p mode?

With bash pattern substitution:
in=$(<original.yml.new)
printf '%s\n' "${in/"$(<before.txt)"/"$(<After.txt)"}" >new.yml

or
mapfile -d '' in <original.yml.new
mapfile -d '' before <before.txt
mapfile -d '' after <After.txt
printf '%s' "${in/"$before"/"$after"}" >new.yml

All the double-quotes are required.

Hey JHNC,
thanks a lot for your comment!
I implemented both solutions without an error :). The first solution provided yielded new.yml. Contentwise, this file was the same as the 'original.yml.new'. I didn't see the additional two lines (or array/object like chepner illustrated in his comment earlier) being in the new.yml file
The same hold for the second solution.

the content to be changed in original.yml.new must exactly match the entirety of before.txt. If there is even a single space difference, nothing will be replaced.

the code works with the 3 files in the question. md5sum are : ef2437f33d8708ce2de6c58913fa8583, 9124a9e2bf83ace6daeca90f87f0eb74, ef5d99eeeb211f48dec8305cd51b041d

First, consider if your settings file is a known format for which you can use a parser, e.g. YAML. Second, you are exposed to a bunch of nasty convoluted shell interpolations by using a one-liner with arbitrary text.
Your one-liner issues.
perl -i -0 -p0e "s/$(cat before.txt)/$(cat after.txt)/se" original.yml.new


-0 is setting the record input separator to \0, which is doing what you want, but only by accident (your file does not contain any null characters). You wanted -0777, which is the idiomatic "slurp mode" used for multiline matches.
-p0e is also most likely working by accident, in that -0 is ignored.
/e flag is trying to eval the substitution text as Perl code. This is a very bad idea and not what you want at all.
The text in your files contains regex metacharacters. You need to escape these before you can use them in the substitution operator.


Put this together and you get:
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;                       # slurp all files
my ($before, $after, $org) = <>;  # slurp filenames as arguments

$org =~ s/\Q$before\E/$after/s;   # substitute
print $org;                       # print changed original

Use like this:
perl foo.pl before.txt after.txt original.txt

Coincidentally this also works as a one-liner:
perl -0777 -e"($bef,$aft,$o) = <>; $o =~ s/\Q$bef\E/$aft/s; print $o" before.txt after.txt org.txt

Because all the text is contained in Perl variables, we don't get any shell interpolation to worry about.
I think this can also be achieved with some innate *nix command.

for "innate",  diff and patch would be an obvious choice

@jhnc Maybe you can make that into an answer.
